# Unordered Output of property file

Tags: java, properties, properties-file

```
List<PData> listproperties = new ArrayList<PData>();
        try
        {
        PData PData = new PData();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        File file = new File("src/Config/object.properties");
        FileInputStream Inputpropertyfile = new FileInputStream(file);
        properties.load(Inputpropertyfile);
        Inputpropertyfile.close();
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Enumeration Keys = properties.keys();
        while(Keys.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String key = (String) Keys.nextElement();//Getting Key from property file.
                String Value = properties.getProperty(key);}}
```

Hi, I am new to java i am trying to import a property file which has huge set of key value pairs , in the above code i was able to import the data but the data imported is in very unordered manner i want to get data in top to bottom , so that i can use it in other class for some functionality ,

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible using `java.util.Properties`. You either need a custom parser, a different file format, or you need to put some sortable prefix in the keys (`001.key1=value`, `002.key2=value`, etc.) and then create a `new TreeMap<>(properties)` and iterate over it instead.

Comment: i gave like 001.key1=value1 and tried but still its the same , do i need to call those 001 orders in my code as well ?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to actually sort the properties after loading them using `TreeMap`, for example (I've updated my answer).

Comment: @bkail treesort will do string comparison. But question is maintaining the order of insertion.

Comment: @SivaKumar As I said in the answer, that's not possible.

Comment: @bkail is there any other method where i can sort it ?? i mean except property file can use .txt or excel file to get my data and sort ?4

Comment: @user3724559 I'm not sure what you're asking. If you can use a different file format like a plain `.txt` file, then you can do whatever you want. For example, you could use `java.io.BufferedReader`, the `readLine` method on that class, and `java.util.LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: Thank you , My aim is to get a key value pair in a order , so that i can use it else where in same order

Comment: Enumeration Keys = properties.keys(); , can i store Keys in a String Array so that i can sort it at this stage .

Comment: `new TreeMap<>(properties).entrySet()` will return an iterator of `Map.Entry` sorted by the key. Or you can use `properties.keySet().toArray(new String[0])` if you really want to sort it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to maintain order

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 * Ordered properties implementation
*/

public class LinkedProperties extends Properties{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<Object, Object> linkMap = new LinkedHashMap<Object,Object>();

    public void clear(){
        linkMap.clear();
    }
    public boolean contains(Object value){
        return linkMap.containsValue(value);
    }
    public boolean containsKey(Object key){
        return linkMap.containsKey(key);
    }
    public boolean containsValue(Object value){
        return linkMap.containsValue(value);
    }
    public Enumeration elements(){
        throw new RuntimeException("Method elements is not supported in LinkedProperties class");
    }
    public Set entrySet(){
        return linkMap.entrySet();
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        return linkMap.equals(o);
    }
    public Object get(Object key){
        return linkMap.get(key);
    }
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        Object oval = get(key); //here the class Properties uses super.get()
        if(oval==null)return null;
        return (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null; //behavior of standard properties
    }
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return linkMap.isEmpty();
    }
    public  Enumeration keys(){
        Set keys=linkMap.keySet();
        return Collections.enumeration(keys);
    }
    public Set keySet(){
        return linkMap.keySet();
    }
    public void list(PrintStream out) {
        this.list(new PrintWriter(out,true));
    }
    public void list(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("-- listing properties --");
        for (Map.Entry e : (Set<Map.Entry>)this.entrySet()){
            String key = (String)e.getKey();
            String val = (String)e.getValue();
            if (val.length() > 40) {
                val = val.substring(0, 37) + "...";
            }
            out.println(key + "=" + val);
        }
    }

    public Object put(Object key, Object value){
        return linkMap.put(key, value);
    }
    public int size(){
        return linkMap.size();
    }
    public Collection values(){
        return linkMap.values();
    }

    //for test purpose only
    public static void main(String[] arg)throws Exception{
        Properties p0=new Properties();
        Properties p1=new LinkedProperties();
        p0.put("aaa","111");
        p0.put("bbb","222");
        p0.put("ccc","333");
        p0.put("ddd","444");

        p1.put("aaa","111");
        p1.put("bbb","222");
        p1.put("ccc","333");
        p1.put("ddd","444");

        System.out.println("\n--"+p0.getClass());
        p0.list(System.out);
        p0.store(System.out,"comments");
        p0.storeToXML(System.out,"comments");
        System.out.println(p0.toString());

        System.out.println("\n--"+p1.getClass());
        p1.list(System.out);
        p1.store(System.out,"comments");
        p1.storeToXML(System.out,"comments");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee this will work (or will continue to work). The implementation of the `load` and `store` methods might operate directly on the underlying `Hashtable` without using the methods you've overloaded.

Comment: ya sure i will implement in my code and ping u back in here :)

Comment: @sankar i should get my property file(object.properties) loaded in public void list(PrintWriter out) method ?

Comment: Yes..You can use and test.

Comment: @sankar it is still unordered :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone i got a clear solution and thought of sharing it here so that everyone can make use of

```
Enumeration Keys = properties.keys();
        List<String> list = Collections.list(Keys);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
        Iterator<String> rows = list.iterator();
```

Using Collections i am getting all the keys and storing it in a list and sorting the entire data i got from my property file